# Having trouble with Dirichlet 3d plot

Tags: r, plot, 3d, dirichlet

I'm trying to create a 3D plot of a random draw from a Dirichlet distribution but it only seems to be plotting in 2 dimensions even though I have data for three variables.

```
draw <- rdirichlet(100, alpha = c(.3,.4,.3))
scatter3D(x ,y, z)
scatterplot3d(draw[,1:3])
```

As you can see, I tried in two ways, using two different packages. In the first, you can see in the image below that they y-values seem to be missing, but I'm not sure why. 
[image]

When I try using a different package, not only are the y-values missing, but the other two values are plotted as if they are on a 45 degree line, which is not correct. Any help is greatly appreciated!
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The y-values are not missing. In your case, a Dirichlet distribution of order 3 will have points that lie on a 2-dimensional simplex (i.e. a 2d plane), since the coordinates for each point must sum to 1. (The pdf plots on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution) may be helpful to see this.)

In your second plot, the points are not actually on a 45-degree line (they just look like it).  The interactive 3d plot from the `rgl` package may be helpful to see this.

```
draw <- gtools::rdirichlet(100, alpha = c(.3, .4, .3))
rgl::plot3d(draw)
```

A plot that looks like this:

[image]

actually has points on a 2d-simplex, which you can see if you rotate it:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Weghuang Wong!